# Undefined variable in table.blade.php of job in laravel

Tags: laravel

File of me:

```
@if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->id == $job->user_id || Auth::user()->id == Auth::user()->role_id <3 ))
    <th> Status </th>
    <th colspan="3">Action</th>
@endif
```

How to fix. I don't understand, please!

Comment: Which variable is undefined? The clue is in the error message

Comment: The error message says that you are trying to access a variable that is undefined (probably `$job`, hard to say with the few details given). Assign/pass the variable to the view and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@if(Auth::check() && $job && (Auth::user()->id == $job->user_id || Auth::user()->id == Auth::user()->role_id <3 ))
    <th> Status </th>
    <th colspan="3">Action</th>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think your blade file will not understand Auth class, instead you can change your code to something like

 @if(auth()->check() && $job && (auth()->user()->id == $job->user_id || auth()->user()->id == auth()->user()->role_id <3 ))
    <th> Status </th>
    <th colspan="3">Action</th>
 @endif

Also make sure you sending job data from your controller to view file
```